# Node.js Plumbing my modules together without it becoming a mess

Tags: javascript, node.js

A simple question really. I have tried to keep my node.js application split out in to relevant modules dependent on features or functionality. E.g. logreading module for reading a log file, IRC module for working with an IRC bot etc.

I currently tie everything together using a global event emitter module which does all the plumbing of any messages that need to be passed, such as log entries that I want to push in to my DB.

This has been working fine for a while now but I'm getting to the point where it feels as though I will need to start requiring some of my functional modules in order to complete some of the work in others. I wanted to keep away from tightly coupling (hence the event module), but is there really anything bad with that?

When reviewing a few other node.js projects I often see a single app.js file with 10 or so other modules being required in which look to be trying to do everything in one place. I am trying to keep mine pretty light and easy to read. Are there any examples of this being done well that you can think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best rule of thumb I've come across is this: Is the module testable in isolation? Can I require the module and call it's functions from test cases? If the module is dependent upon other modules, how hard is it for me to mock those modules with fake ones for testing?

Testability is the best indicator of good separation of concerns, in my opinion. It's okay if your module requires ten other modules if it really does require them. I would just always keep testability in the back of your mind, even if you're not actually going to dedicate time to writing tests.

Even just keeping the option of testing open is better than nothing, and it's a useful guide for how specialized your modules are. If you have three modules and you can't use one without the other two, then maybe they belong in one module. Or maybe those three modules are big and easier to navigate while split up; for that scenario I usually create a *wrapper module*.

I create a directory with a relevant name and I throw an `index.js` file in there which requires the other three modules (or whatever it is I need). Then from the rest of my app I can access that module as if it's one specialized API, even though internally it's complex and split up into multiple submodules. The wrapper module hides that mess from the rest of my app so that I can still be modular while also keeping the API simple. It's a great workaround for those situations where combining stuff into one module is too messy and utilizing the module(s) while in the split up configuration is also messy.

If a module is generic enough (which I usually aim for if possible) then I'll often publish it to NPM as a standalone module. Then I'll just require it in my project like any other module on NPM. For example, I kept writing a script to load all my mongoose models into a single `db` object for easy access. The code would loop through my mongodb model files in a `dbmodels` directory at the root of my project. It would require the module, register the model data with mongoose, and generate a simple `db` object that I could use (e.g. `db.User.findOne({ username: 'munkee' }, function (err, user) { ... }`).

Instead of continuing to copy and paste the same blob of code into every project I built, I created a generic NPM module called [mongoose-simpledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-simpledb). If you look at [the code for that module](https://github.com/codetunnel/mongoose-simpledb/blob/master/index.js) you can see that it's not very complex. It's generic and useful enough though that I think it deserves it's own place in the NPM registry. It has made things a lot easier in newer projects. Other people finding it useful too is just a happy bonus :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this out. I'm very new to node but from my experience in other languages (non-js) you often get a feeling when things feel a bit out of place or "hacky". The wrapper sounds useful in fact I can see a place for it right now to split up another module a little better. I'll keep your comments in mind and have another look at my app overall. The following is my current project: https://github.com/Hardware-Hacks/node-p3negram telegram messenger <---> irc

Comment: Good luck! Just remember that we're talking about a perfect world here. Sometimes there is no solution that doesn't feel a little "hacky", but those are rapidly becoming a thing of the past in node as more and more modules solve harder and harder problems for us. At any rate, it looks like a fun project :)